# Does limit exist for the following expression?

Tags: calculus, limits, summation, logarithms

If limit exists, then what is its value? And if it does not exist then can we find where does this expression tends as $ n \to \infty$.

The expression :
 $\lim\limits_{n \to  \infty }  \sum\limits_{k=1}^n - (-1)^{k} \ln \left(\frac{1}{k}\right)$

Answer (score 0):

For a sum $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ to converge, a **necessary** condition is that

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} a_k = 0,$$

which is not the case here. Therefore, your sum diverges.

Comment: We can write the above expression as $-\ln(1)+\ln(2)-\ln(3)+\ln(4)-\ln(5)...\infty$ and $\ln(1) = 0$ , thus it becomes : $\ln(2)-\ln(3)+\ln(4)-\ln(5)-\ln(6)...\infty$ which can be written as $\ln\left(\frac{2}{3}\right) + \ln\left(\frac{4}{5}\right) + \ln\left(\frac{6}{7}\right) + \ln\left(\frac{8}{9}\right) + \ln\left(\frac{10}{11}\right) + .... \ln\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)$; and as $n\to\infty$, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right) = 1$ thus $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}ln\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)=0$ , that is $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} a_k = 0$, so it should **converge**.

Answer (score -2):

The sum can be simplified as

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n - (-1)^{k} \ln \left(\frac{1}{k}\right)
=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n  (-1)^{k} \ln k
$.

This sum diverges.
However,
let's see how it behaves for
even and odd numbre of terms.

For an even number of terms,

$\begin{array}\\
S_{2n}
&=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n}  (-1)^{k} \ln k\\
&=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} (- \ln (2k-1)+\ln(2k))\\
&=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} (- \ln (\frac{2k-1}{2k})\\
&=-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}  \ln (1-\frac{1}{2k})\\
&\approx-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} -(\frac{1}{2k}+\frac{1}{8k^2}+ ...)\\
&=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2k}+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}(\frac{1}{8k^2}+ ...)\\
&=\frac12 H_n+C
\quad\text{for some constant } C \text{ and large } n\\
&\approx\frac12 (\ln(n)+\gamma)+C\\
&=\frac12 \ln(n)+C_1\\
\end{array}
$

Note that
$C_1
=C+\frac12 \gamma
$
and
$C
= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\frac1{m(2k)^m }
= \sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\frac1{m2^m}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac1{ k^m }
= \sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\frac1{m2^m}\zeta(m)
$
which converges and is
easily computed.

For an odd number of terms,

$\begin{array}\\
S_{2n+1}
&= S_{2n}-\ln(2n+1)\\
&\approx \frac12 \ln(n)+C_1-\ln(2n+1)\\
&= \frac12 \ln(n)+C_1-(\ln 2 + \ln(n+\frac12))\\
&= \frac12 \ln(n)+C_1-(\ln 2 + \ln(n)+\ln(1+\frac1{2n}))\\
&= -\frac12 \ln(n)+C_1-\ln 2+\frac1{2n}+O(\frac1{n^2}))\\
&\approx -\frac12 \ln(n)+C_1-\ln 2\\
\end{array}
$

If we average the
even and odd sums,
$\frac12(S_{2n}+S_{2n+1})
\approx C_1-\frac12\ln 2
$.

This can be considered as
the limit of the sum
and
$C_1$
can be computed as
described previously.

Comment: Thank You very much for your answer, but I can't understand how does it diverge.

Comment: Since $\ln (1/k) =-\ln(k)$, the terms of the sum are unbounded. Perhaps you meant $\ln(1-1/k)$. If so, please ask this as another question instead of editing this one. If my guess is correct, look up the Wallis product.

Comment: Why the downvote? I produced a nonstandard summation method which gave a value.

Comment: I didn't do it.

Comment: We can write the above expression as $-\ln(1)+\ln(2)-\ln(3)+\ln(4)-\ln(5)...\infty$ and $\ln(1) = 0$ , thus it becomes : $\ln(2)-\ln(3)+\ln(4)-\ln(5)-\ln(6)...\infty$ which can be written as $\ln\left(\frac{2}{3}\right) + \ln\left(\frac{4}{5}\right) + \ln\left(\frac{6}{7}\right) + \ln\left(\frac{8}{9}\right) + \ln\left(\frac{10}{11}\right) + .... \ln\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)$; and as $n\to\infty$, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right) = 1$ thus $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}ln\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)=0$ , so it should **converge**.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not. $\ln(1-1/n) \approx -1/n$ and the sum of these does not converge.